# how to find two numbers to minimize the sum of squares

Tags: regression

Suppose we are given a sequence of positive numbers
$0<a_1<a_2< \cdots < a_n$.

Step 1. Choose an integer $m$ where $m \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. After choosing $m$, we divide our numbers into two subgroups $\{a_1,\cdots,a_m\}$ and $\{a_{m+1},\cdots,a_n\}$.

Step 2. Given two numbers $a', a'' \in \mathbb{R}$,
we can calculate the sum of squares in the two subgroups
$$SS = \sum_{i=1}^{m} (a_i-a')^2+\sum_{j=m+1}^n (a_j-a'')^2.$$

My question is how to choose $m, a', a''$ to minimize the $SS$.

The $a'$ and $a''$ are easy to solve. In fact, $a'$ should be the mean of the first subgroup, i.e. $\frac{a_1+\cdots + a_m}{m}$ and $a''$
should be the mean of the second subgroup, i.e. $\frac{a_{m+1}+\cdots + a_n}{n-m}$.

To solve $m$, I guess that we can firstly compute the mean $\bar{a}$ of the whole group, i.e. $\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}$ and then $m$ should be the largest integer such that $a_m<\bar{a}$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: To the close-voter: I would understand voting to close as "belongs on Math.SE", but I don't quite understand what about this question "needs details or clarity".

Comment: Please do not cross post.  It is against SE policy & wastes a lot of people's time.  I'll migrate this to [math.SE] where the threads can be merged.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would likely be to calculate your target sum from step 2 for each $m\in\{1, \dots, n\}$, giving you $m$ sums $S_1, \dots, S_m$. Then just pick the $m$ giving you the smallest such $S_m$.

You can either do this straightforwardly or use an online algorithm to minimize the amount of calculation if this is an issue to you. [Online estimation of variance with limited memory](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/235129/1352) gives you an online way of calculating $\sum_{i=1}^m(a_i-a')^2$ for $m=1, \dots, n$ and should be easily modified for the second sum.

Unfortunately, it is *not* the case that $S_m$ is convex as a function of $m$ (which would allow you to do a faster search), e.g. for $$a=(0.01,0.09,0.48,0.49,0.55,0.6,0.86,0.95,0.97,1).$$

[image: S]

R code:

```
aa <- c(0.01, 0.09, 0.48, 0.49, 0.55, 0.6, 0.86, 0.95, 0.97, 1)
S <- sapply(seq_along(aa),function(ii)
    sum((aa[1:ii]-mean(aa[1:ii]))^2)+sum((aa[-(1:ii)]-mean(aa[-(1:ii)]))^2))
plot(S,type="o",xlab="m",pch=19)
```

In addition, your hypothesis (calculate $\bar{a}$, pick the largest $m$ such that $a_m<\bar{a}$) does not work, either: use

$$ a = (0.06, 0.26, 0.38, 0.51, 0.61, 0.76, 0.81, 0.94, 0.96, 0.98). $$

Then

$$ \bar{a} = 0.627\quad\text{and}\quad\max\{m|a_m<\bar{a}\}=5, $$

but (rounding to the third digit)

$$ S=(0.559, 0.371, 0.252, 0.214, 0.224, 0.334, 0.441, 0.622, 0.777, 
0.916) $$

and

$$ S_4=\min S.$$

(Incidentally, note that in this case $S_m$ *is* convex, so your hypothesis does not even work in the convex case.)

Comment: I am very sorry. There is a typo in the question. I am looking for the smallest sum instead of the largest because in Random Forest when growing a decision tree, I need to minimize such a sum.

Comment: I edited my answer, it should be correct for your corrected question.

Comment: Note that on Math.se someone suggests in a comment that this is NP-hard.

Comment: If the $d$-dimensional analogue is NP-hard (per the commenter), that doesn't mean it is so in one dimension. The simplest solution is just to calculate the sums, which is polynomial in $n$, and do this for $m=1, \dots, n$. This is completely polynomial, even without looking at online/streaming algorithms.